# Data Binding for specific attributes

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

Consider the following angular code fragment

```
<li ng-repeat="i in [1,2]" class="{{i}}" onclick="alert({{i}})">
  Hello - {{i}}
</li>
```

The output html is

```
<li ng-repeat="i in [1,2]" class="1" onclick="alert({{i}})">
  Hello - 1
</li>
<li ng-repeat="i in [1,2]" class="2" onclick="alert({{i}})">
  Hello - 2
```

Note that in the above for the value of the `class` attribute the databinding syntax works whereas it does not work for the value part of `onclick` attribute.  Why?

Comment: Why you are using native `onclick` instead of angulars `ng-click`? And I think you don't need to put those template syntax (`{{}}`) inside function parameter just pass `i`

Comment: the behaviour is the same for certain arbritary attributes - for example, if I specify `onclick2` as the attribute name, it bind correctly. If the attribute name is `onxmouseover` (note the intentional `x` in the name) it does not.  Looks like some attributes are handled differently.  The question is why and what are those attributes?

Comment: Have a look at the console - you should see a couple of compile errors with the message "Interpolations for HTML DOM event attributes are disallowed.  Please use the ng- versions...." Angular uses the regex /^(on[a-z]+|formaction)$/ to identify the DOM attributes. Surprised that onclick2 and onxmouseover interpolated correctly.

Comment: numerals are not a part of the regex :)

Comment: You're right; onclick2 is parsed correctly but onxmouseover isn't.